# Selenium/xpath attaining text from dropdown menu

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

In Selenium, is there a way to get text from a dropdown menu and then put into a list in Python?

Suppose:

```
<select id="zoo">
    <option value="30">
    Lion
    </option>

    <option value="10">
    Elephant
    </option>

    <option value="5">
    Zebra
    </option>
</select>
```

How can I put Lion, Elephant, and Zebra into a list?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) and get the [`.options`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.options):

> `options`
>
> Returns a list of all options belonging to this select tag

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('zoo'))
print [option.text for option in select.options]
```

where `driver` is a `webdriver` instance.

DEMO (using [this w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select) (yeah, sorry for w3schools :)):

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get('http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select')
>>> driver.switch_to.frame('view')
>>> select = Select(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('select'))
>>> [option.text for option in select.options]
[u'Volvo', u'Saab', u'Opel', u'Audi']
```

Note that `select` element on this page doesn't have an `id`, so I just find it using `find_element_by_tag_name()`. Also note that there are `iframes` there, so I have to switch to the appropriate `iframe` to be able to find the element.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help. I do keep getting the same error however:   TypeError: iteration over non-sequence       Perhaps I'm not successfully finding the Select element?

Comment: @user2631667 you are welcome, can you show the code you are using and the full error traceback? Would help to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here's what worked for me:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('select'))

text_list = []

for option in select.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    text_list.append(option.text)
```

Thanks for the help!